# Google translator top bar hide

Tags: google-translator-toolkit

I am using google translator for my website. I want to hide the top bar of google translator let me know how i can hide that one?

Please check my site link here http://www.rewords.com and let me know i to hide that bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Done via CSS:

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {display: none !important;} 
body { top: 0px !important; }
```

Comment: As this does work, I am using `opencart` and it gives this jumping effect for the page...hence when translator is loading and although `css` is in `<head>`, page moves down and then back up, any ideas on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 11):

Some changes in Jacob's answer. Try writing,

```
<style type="text/css">iframe.goog-te-banner-frame{ display: none !important;}</style>
<style type="text/css">body {position: static !important; top:0px !important;}</style>
```

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

hide  by adding a javascript on your body onload event

```
document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")[0].rows="0,*;
```

Comment: Sorry sushanth i didn't get what you mean? Have you checked my URL the google  bar is coming after language transalation. Please can you give me proper syntax? Please

Answer (score 0):

The body element will fall into the flow - with static.
Then you can properly use the display of none.

```
  body {top: 0px !important; position: static !important; }
    .goog-te-banner-frame {display:none !important}
```

Comment: Please take a minute to describe what your code does and how it solves the author's question.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody want javascript to do the job, add the snippet below in your *document.ready*

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-banner-frame skiptranslate')[0] !== undefined) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-banner-frame skiptranslate')[0].style.display  = 'none';
  document.body.style.top = '0px';
}
```

**How it works**:
Google loads the toolbar to an iframe with class 'goog-te-banner-frame skiptranslate' and add 40px margin to top of html body. So we hide that frame and set body margin to '0px'.

**Note**: Refer to the attribution requirements by google https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution

Answer (score 0):

Using some of the code from KDawg, adding margin-top and absolute positioning, I found this addition to the CSS to be the solution for positioning the hidden translation banner only, which doesn't appear until after a language is selected.

This solution does not affect positioning of translate button, or the language selector, which remains on the fixed header.

```
} iframe.goog-te-banner-frame {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:30px;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it using CSS, Just go and put below CSS code in style tag. That's it..!

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
        display: none !important;
    } 
    body {
        top: 0px !important; 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide some text to support the code you have added.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.skiptranslate iframe  {
visibility: hidden !important;
    } 
body{
    top:0!important;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To this very time, solutions proposed here correctly hide the bar, yet the page remains shifted down 40px, hiding my footer and the bottom of my main frame.

After thinking about trapping body change event to look for the bar height and put it as a padding down my body, keeping the bar visible.
Yet I found quite a light solution by adding a single line to google's required function itself, for it seems TranslateElement forces the body position to relative, making the CSS body{position useless to set.

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage:'en'},'google_translate_element');
      document.body.style.position="static"; /* << to counter overwriting by google func */
      document.body.style.top="0px";         /* << force body pos here if not in CSS     */
    }
  </script>
  ...
</head>
```

and just keep using the style changes some of you already proposed, thank you.

**CSS**

```
body > .skiptranslate { display: none; }        /*     << /!\ hides the bar     */
```

I guess the next google move will be to also force body{top, so I prefer it in the JS call to their function.

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply try it in Root CSS:**

```
.skiptranslate>iframe {
  display: none !important;
  z-index: -1;
}
body {
 .......
  top: 0px !important;
}
```

If you `need more` info please comment here.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried several ways, and below one helped me to solve the problem

```
body {
    top: 0px !important;
}
body > .skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
}
```