# Hiding Google Translate bar

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="" class="skiptranslate">
  <iframe frameborder="0" style="visibility:visible" 
          src="javascript:''" 
          class="goog-te-banner-frame skiptranslate" 
          id=":2.container"></iframe>
</div>
```

I need to hide it but if I only hide the goog-te-banner-frame using:

```
.goog-te-banner-frame {
    display:none !important
    }
```

It still throws my header down. If I use this:

```
.skiptranslate {
    display:none !important
    }
```

It also hides the language selection dropdown because it shares the same class.
I'd like to hide the skiptranslate div that CONTAINS the goog-te-banner-frame.

How do I do that?

Edit:
This is actual code to "create" the translate div above:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', 
        layout:     google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
        autoDisplay: false, 
        includedLanguages: ''}, 'google_translate_element');}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try using visibility:hidden?

Comment: Find detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42368593/5466401

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Ok, this works for some reason:

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
    } 
body {
    top: 0px !important; 
    }
```

Comment: Old I know but I thought a better description is worth being put here rather than 'working for some reason'. When the translate bar is displayed, Google displays the translate bar which is 40px high and then adds the top property to the body to make room for the translate bar without sitting over the top of the content.

Comment: thats why I need to remove it when using floating header navigation, its works good.

Comment: As this does work, I am using `opencart` and it gives this jumping effect for the page...hence when translator is loading and although `css` is in `<head>`, page moves down and then back up, any ideas on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 21):

**The selected answer is wrong!**

I know this is an old question, but for anyone coming across this problem in the future, the easiest way:

```
body > .skiptranslate {
    display: none;
}
```

Since the iframes are dynamically added directly to the body, you can simply select only direct descendants and nothing deeper.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  The automatically added translate bar was redundant and and blocked the app's navbar. This fixed it +1

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
}
body {
    top: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

```
.goog-te-gadget img{
    display:none !important;
}
body > .skiptranslate {
    display: none;
}
body {
    top: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add directly this, to hide that bar into your entire project/pages.

```
.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
}

body {
    top: 0px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another class, say `.myClass {display: none;}`, append to skiptranslate, like `class="skiptranslate myClass"`

EDIT:

Another solution:
You can also wrap the google translate code with another div, say `<div id="google-wrapper">... google translate code...</div>` and then style the wrapper with `display: none;`

OR

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SryPD/

Comment: I can't because it is generated by the Google translate code. See above.

Comment: @MB34 You can wrap the google translate code with another div, say `<div id="google-wrapper">... google translate code...</div>` and then style the wrapper with `display: none;`

Comment: Tried that, too, still no go because it is dynamically generated.

Comment: I am trying this and it still doesn't hide the parent div: .goog-te-banner-frame div:parent

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add an id to the `skiptranslate` div that holds the goog-te-banner-frame? `<div id="something" class="skiptranslate" style="">` will then allow you to style `div#something { display: none !important; }`

Comment: See comment on Dexter's post.

Comment: @MB34 You can wrap the google translate code with another div, say `<div id="google-wrapper">... google translate code...</div>` and then style the wrapper with `display: none;`

Comment: This approach seems not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work the best for me. I send the Google Translate "origninal text" tooltip to z-index: -1000. So it is still in the page, but out of sight.

```
                            // Force hiding of "original text" popup for menus, etc. (very annoying)
                        jQuery(selector).bind(
                            "mouseenter mouseleave",
                            function (event) {
                                if (event.type === 'mouseenter')    { google_trans_tt.css('z-index', -1000); }
                                else                                { google_trans_tt.css('z-index',  1000); }
                            }
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

October 2022: None of the above answers worked in my case.

I made it work by simply changing the *z-index:* of my website's menus, after I found the *z-index:* of the google translate's iframe (using of course the Developers Tools).[image]

Answer (score 0):

this work form me

```
.VIpgJd-ZVi9od-ORHb-OEVmcd{
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me as I recently fixed mine.

```
    body {
     top: 0px !important;
    }

    body > .skiptranslate > iframe.skiptranslate {
     display: none !important;
     visibility: hidden !important;
    }
```