# How to hide title bar via Google Translation Javascript API on Desktop and Mobile

Tags: javascript, google-translator-toolkit

While using the Google Translation API, I see a title bar appearing on the Top of the page (on Both Desktop and Mobile. I would like to check if there is a feasible way to hide this bar and also powered by Google.

Also, if it's legal to do so.

Seeking your suggestion.Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
   display: none !important;
} 
body {
   top: 0px !important; 
}
```

Or give us the CSS class :)

Source : [Hiding Google Translate bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248673/hiding-google-translate-bar)