# Can I disable the "google translate bar" via userchrome?

Tags: css, firefox, google-translate

Question as above. I'm using Firefox 66, 64 bit.
I might have gotten something wrong as I'm totally new to css/userchrome.

I tried the solutions posted in [Google translator top bar hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197072/google-translator-top-bar-hide) and [Hiding Google Translate bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248673/hiding-google-translate-bar), but they did not work.
Most of the threads I found, though, are either from before Firefox "quantum" or ask to disable the translation bar on specifically on the website of OP.

Comment: Use userContent.css, not userChrome.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mr Lister stated in the comments, it's gotta be in the userContent.css (in the same chrome folder, though).

Adding

```
body > .skiptranslate {
    display: none;
}
```

there, as posted in [Hiding Google Translate bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248673/hiding-google-translate-bar), hid the translate bar without any (immediately noticeable) issues.